# How to prevent drawables from refreshing on recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, android-recyclerview

I made a button, which when clicked changes values on the database,
the status/color of the button is based on the value on the database.

How to prevent all drawables from getting refreshed on recyclerview just because one drawable had its value changed?

Result i get:
https://media.giphy.com/media/frHERBcrLUA8x14bsh/giphy.gif

```
public MainAdapter(Context mContext, List<Posts> mPost)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Main Adapter Start");
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mPost = mPost;
 }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.all_posts_layout, viewGroup, false);
            return new MainAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
final Posts post = mPost.get(position);
        final String Postkey = post.getPost_uid();
        final String likes = Integer.toString(post.getLikes());

        holder.setUpStatus(Postkey);

        LikesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                holder.LikepostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {

                        LikeChecker = true;

                        LikesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                            {
                                if (LikeChecker.equals(true))
                                {

                                    if (dataSnapshot.child(Postkey).hasChild(currentUserID)) {
                                        LikesRef.child(Postkey).child(currentUserID).removeValue();

                                        PostsRef.child(Postkey).child("likes").setValue(post.getLikes()-1);
                                        LikeChecker = false;

                                    } else {

                                        LikesRef.child(Postkey).child(currentUserID).setValue(true);

                                        DisikesRef.child(Postkey).child(currentUserID).removeValue();
                                        StoreToHistory(Postkey);

                                        DisikesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                if (dataSnapshot.child(currentUserID).exists())
                                                {
                                                    PostsRef.child(Postkey).child("likes").setValue(post.getLikes()+2);
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    PostsRef.child(Postkey).child("likes").setValue(post.getLikes()+1);
                                                }
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                            }
                                        });
                                        LikeChecker = false;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            }
                        });
                    }});
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
    }
@Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {


        return mPost.size();
    }
```

ViewHolder:

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;
        ImageButton LikepostButton, DislikepostButton;
        int countLikes, countDislikes, countComms;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

            currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

            LikepostButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_button);
            DislikepostButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dislike);
            CommentPostButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_button);
            DisplayNoOfLikes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.display_number_of_likes);
            DisplayNoOfDislikes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.display_number_of_dislikes);
        }


        public void setUpStatus(final String PostKey)
        {
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ups");

            reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if (dataSnapshot.child(PostKey).hasChild(currentUserID))
                    {
LikepostButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.upvote);
                        DisplayNoOfLikes.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f14c00"));

                    }
                    else
                    {
LikepostButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.upvote_novote); 
}
                    DisikesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            if (dataSnapshot.child(PostKey).hasChild(currentUserID))
                            {
                                DislikepostButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.downvote_orange);
DisplayNoOfLikes.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#df3168a7"));
                            }
                            else {
                               DislikepostButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.downvote_novote);
                            }
                        }
 @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    }); }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
}
            });

        }
```

Comment: Example of your code?

Comment: @Yupi added, sorry for that

Comment: You are listening for values in `onBindViewHolder` by calling `holder.setUpStatus(Postkey);` I think that is why your `drawable` image is flashing. Try comment out this method and see what will happen.

Comment: @Yupi I tried, although now its not flashing, I cant see the drawable anymore, because holder.,setUpStatus(Postkey); is setting up the resource of the drawable,
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I think the whole approach is not good because of network calls in `onBindViewHolder` which you should definitely avoid. That is connecting internet to many times basically on each scroll, which is bad architecture and faster battery drain. 
You should consider storing keys into `List<String>` for each post. `List` has method called `contains`, and it will give you the answer is key inside `List` or not.

Comment: @Yupi sorry for my my ignorance but I dont know how to implement this, can you please give me hand of help with the code?

Comment: You should store all keys in database in `List` so whoever likes your post add his key to that `List`. And when getting data about each post you will also get all keys of users which liked particular post. And than inside `onBindViewHolder` you can check does that list contains particular key or not.

Comment: @Yupi will check, thanks!

Comment: @Yupi I would like to thank you , your solution worked nicely and smooth !